# Consulta com conexão em mais de um banco php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 3 bancos de dados e estou buscando informações nos três, mais na minha primeira consulta já me deparei para um um erro:

É como se a consulta estivesse buscando em outro banco que não é o que escolhi,segue abaixo a minha consulta,a mensagem de erro e meu arquivo de conexão.

> Consulta:

```
 $query_pesquisa = mysql_query(" SELECT 
    o.numero AS CHAMADO,
    p.problema AS PROBLEMA,
    o.descricao AS DESCRICAO,
    o.contato AS CONTATO,
    o.telefone AS TELEFONE,
    o.data_abertura AS DATA_DE_ABERTURA,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF (HOUR, str_to_date(data_abertura,'%Y-%m-%d'), CURDATE()) as HORAS_EM_ABERTO,
    i.inst_nome AS UNIDADE,
    a.sistema AS AREA,
    l.local AS SETOR,
    u.nome AS TECNICO,
    ua.nome AS ABERTO_POR,
    s.status AS STATUS
    /*sls.slas_tempo AS TEMPO_DE_SOLUCAO*/
FROM
    ocorrencias AS o
        LEFT JOIN
    sistemas AS a ON a.sis_id = o.sistema
        LEFT JOIN
    localizacao AS l ON l.loc_id = o.local
        LEFT JOIN
    instituicao AS i ON i.inst_cod = o.instituicao
        LEFT JOIN
    usuarios AS u ON u.user_id = o.operador
        LEFT JOIN
    usuarios AS ua ON ua.user_id = o.aberto_por
        LEFT JOIN
    `status` AS s ON s.stat_id = o.status
        LEFT JOIN
    status_categ AS stc ON stc.stc_cod = s.stat_cat
        LEFT JOIN
    problemas AS p ON p.prob_id = o.problema
        LEFT JOIN
    sla_solucao AS sls ON sls.slas_cod = p.prob_sla
        LEFT JOIN
    prioridades AS pr ON pr.prior_cod = l.loc_prior
        LEFT JOIN
    sla_solucao AS slr ON slr.slas_cod = pr.prior_sla
        LEFT JOIN
    script_solution AS sol ON sol.script_cod = o.oco_script_sol
        LEFT JOIN
    prior_atend AS prioridade_atendimento ON prioridade_atendimento.pr_cod = o.oco_prior
WHERE
        a.sistema = 'Ti'
        AND o.status IN (1 , 2)
ORDER BY numero ASC",$ConnOcomon)or die(mysql_error());

    if (empty($query_pesquisa)) {
    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
    }
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_pesquisa);
```

> Conexão:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 //BANCO FOLLOWUP
$local_serve1       = "127.0.0.1";  
$usuario_serve1     = "root";     
$senha_serve1       = "";             
$banco_de_dados1    = "bigchamados";      
$ConnChamados       = mysql_connect($local_serve1,$usuario_serve1,$senha_serve1) or die ("O servidor não responde!");
$db1                = mysql_select_db($banco_de_dados1,$ConnChamados)            or die ("Não foi possivel conectar-se ao banco de dados!"); 

// BANCO OCOMON
$local_serve2       = "127.0.0.1";  
$usuario_serve2     = "root";     
$senha_serve2       = "";             
$banco_de_dados2    = "ocomon_rc6";      
$ConnOcomon         = mysql_connect($local_serve2,$usuario_serve2,$senha_serve2) or die ("O servidor não responde!");
$db2                = mysql_select_db($banco_de_dados2,$ConnOcomon)              or die ("Não foi possivel conectar-se ao banco de dados!");

//BANCO USUÁRIOS
$local_serve3       = "127.0.0.1";
$usuario_serve3     = "root";
$senha_serve3       = "";
$banco_de_dados3    = "bigcadastro";
$ConnUser           = mysql_connect($local_serve3,$usuario_serve3,$senha_serve3) or die ("O servidor não responde!");
$db3                = mysql_select_db($banco_de_dados3,$ConnUser)                or die ("Não foi possivel conectar-se ao banco de dados!");


  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
  mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
  mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8'); 
?>
```

> Mensagem de erro:

```
Table 'bigcadastro.ocorrencias' doesn't exist
```

Comment: A primeira consulta vc diz `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` ?

Comment: Não,essa parte ai,é somente para tratamento da acentuação de caracteres. veja: http://phpbrasil.com/artigo/11qDFvxJBUXI/lidando-com-utf-8-com-o-php-e-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeira questão e verificar o banco de dados, sua estrutura interna. Como ela não foi postada vou assumir que o banco de dados `ocomon_rc6` realmente possui a tabela `ocorrencias`.  Segundo, o código que você postou está incompleto, deveria postar o código todo para que pudesse entender a sua lógica.

Mas basicamente é o seguinte, o banco que você ta usando não possui a tabela que você esta acessando (obviamente) das duas umas:

1. você esta passando a conexão errada para realizar essa consulta;
2. você esta omitindo sem querer o `link_identifier` da conexão, desta forma o PHP usa o último link aberto por `mysql_connect`(), na documentação [disponível aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php) você pode conferir esse comportamento:

   > **link_identifier** A conexão MySQL. Se o link identifier não for especificado, o último link aberto por mysql_connect() é utilizado. Se
   >   uma conexão anterior não existir será tentado criar um a partir de uma
   >   chadama a mysql_connect() sem nenhum argumento. Se nenhuma conexão for
   >   encontrada ou estabelecida, um erro nível E_WARNING é gerado.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a ligação com o resultado que preciso, poderia me passar um exemplo ?

Answer (score -1):

O cuidado que deve ter, em sistemas com mais de um BD, é que ele, logicamente, se torna um sistema com várias **CONEXÕES**.

O que vejo são os dados e todos conectando ao mesmo tempo, assim que se faz o include do arquivo de conexão.

Minha primeira sugestão: separe as conexões, dê o `include` da principal, e quando for usar as outras, não se esqueça de usar `mysqli_close()`.

Minha segunda sugestão: Se for o caso da necessidade de TODAS estarem conectadas ao mesmo tempo, receio que deve dar uma olhada em `webservers`, assim, uma concorrência de dados é encarada de uma forma mais organizada. Em inglês, o site do PHP mostra algo com [conexões concorrentes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Minha terceira sugestão: `websockets`. Como diz a sua concepção da palavra:

> é uma tecnologia que permite a comunicação bidirecional por canais full-duplex sobre um único soquete Transmission Control Protocol (TCP). Ele é projetado para ser executado em browsers e servidores web que suportem o HTML5, mas pode ser usado por qualquer cliente ou servidor de aplicativos.

Comment: Terei uma tela só, e nele usarei as 3 conexões, pois será um painel,por isso estou conectando aos 3,o que eu poderia fazer nesse caso ?

Comment: Editei a resposta com minhas ideias.

Comment: Poderiam explicar a negativação da resposta, ou um exemplo, ou até mesmo onde errei. Ambos perder reputação é bem ruim pra comunidade.

Answer (score -1):

Não há muito a complementar, mas o fato de não buscar no lugar certo é por que não esta indicando o lugar a ser buscado,

Exemplo:

```
$sql = '...';

// Para buscar no banco bigchamados
mysql_query( $sql, $db1 );

// Para buscar no banco ocomon_rc6
mysql_query( $sql, $db2 );

// Para buscar no banco bigcadastro
mysql_query( $sql, $db3 );
```